# Using AC connectors with DC voltage

Tags: dc

I have a 90 volt gearmotor and would like to use an AC voltage twistlock style plug for ease of motor replacement. Is this an acceptable use (per code) or does it not make any difference? Thanks

Comment: what code? , you're not using the grid.

Comment: Do the connectors you have in mind have a DC rating? I don't think standard Hubbell twist-locks have such a manufacturer's rating.

Comment: If you are pretty sure that you will not disconnect under load, it is probably OK as a practical matter. If you plan to connect/disconnect while the motor is running, maybe your contacts will experience arcing. I don't think there is any applicable code. I would probably select a connector with a DC rating.

Comment: Do Not Do This.  Use a dedicated DC power connector.  If you use a standard AC twist lock, it will, with 100% certainty, be plugged into a matching AC receptacle at some point in the future.

Comment: The motor is used on a steam "tunnel" in a distribution center. Once in a while we have to swap the motor for maintenance (oil leaks) and as it is connected now we have to physically disconnect the wiring at the J box. I would like to be able to "unplug" the cord to old motor and plug in the new motor without having to open the J box. Machine is stand alone and would be locked out during this maintenance. No chance of it being plugged into any AC power. Thanks so much for the replies!!

Answer (score 4):

You have three things to consider, and these are not necessarily in order of importance

a) whether it 'works' electrically
b) insurance and liability issues
c) servicing by other people

a) 90v is higher than the generally recognised 'safe touch' voltage of around 40v. As long as the connector is adequately insulated for the voltage, and conductors sized for the current, that should be OK.

b) Is this a one-off for your own use, or something you're selling? Either way, if it fails bad and causes damage, will the 'off rating' use (misuse) of this connector void any insurance that's covering your property, or lives of nearest and dearest? That's what UL ratings are on components for, when used within their ratings, they are deemed to be OK. Use outside their ratings, even if it looks OK for the purpose, then all insurance bets are off. It is insurance companies' main job to wriggle out of liability on the slightest pretext they can find. An off rating connector in the thing that started the fire, even if it wasn't the component that started the fire, is just what they're looking for.

c) The components used tell a story to a somebody opening up the equipment to mend it, or learn from it. Will the connector mislead, and cause a hazard, because of its 'off rating' use? You may think it's OK to use a mains connector to connect some low voltage circuits together, but what happens if somebody else sees a mains connector, and connects it to mains? Don't embed hazardous surprises for someone else to find.

Comment: The motor is used on a steam "tunnel" in a distribution center. Once in a while we have to swap the motor for maintenance (oil leaks) and as it is connected now we have to physically disconnect the wiring at the J box. I would like to be able to "unplug" the cord to old motor and plug in the new motor without having to open the J box. Machine is stand alone and would be locked out during this maintenance. No chance of it being plugged into any AC power. Thanks so much for the replies!!

Comment: @G.Adams I'm not sure what a steam tunnel is, but a distribution center sounds like a commercial operation where other people work and you're not responsible for the insurance. Find a connector that cannot be plugged into mains, or at the very least is non-standard. Might be worth linking to the twistlock connector you are thinking of. I've heard people say 'no chance of ...', before later it happened. It needs to be 'no physical possibility of ...'

Comment: A Steam Tunnel is a machine that steams clothing as they pass through. The motor is what drives the chain that carries the clothing through the machine. The motor would have maybe an 18 inch lead on it and the supply "pig tail" would only be about 6-8 inches long. It would be physically impossible to plug it into a nearby AC outlet. There are none available within 25-30 feet. I was planning on using the 3 prong twistlock plugs and there is nothing like it anywhere on this machine. I would like to thank you for the info. You may be able to tell that I am not an electrician but my boss is.